# $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$. It is also known that $P(X ≤ 160) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X ≤ 140) = \frac{1}{4}.$ What are the values of $µ$ and $σ$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

A random variable $X$ is know to be distributed according to a normal
distribution. It is also known that $P(X ≤ 160) = \frac{1}{2}$
and $P(X ≤ 140) = \frac{1}{4}.$

What are the values of $µ$ and $σ$?

My solution :

$P(X\leq160)=P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq\frac{160-\mu}{\sigma})\overset{Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}}{=}$
$P(Z\leq\frac{160-\mu}{\sigma})=\phi(\frac{160-\mu}{\sigma})=\frac{1}{2}$

$P(X\leq140)=P(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\leq\frac{140-\mu}{\sigma})\overset{Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}}{=}$
$P(Z\leq\frac{140-\mu}{\sigma})=\phi(\frac{140-\mu}{\sigma})=\frac{1}{4}$

I think I need to find the values with this table:
[image]

I don't know how to do it and be grateful for some help , Thank you !

Comment: Do you know that the normal distribution is symmetrical about the $\mu$. What does this tell you about $Pr(X < \mu)$ and $Pr(X > \mu)$? Once you find the $\mu$ through this hint: You can substitute it into your z-score function to solve for $\sigma$, using the equation $Pr(X < 140) = \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $P(X\leq 160)=1/2$, we deduce that the normally distributed random variable $X$ has mean $\mu=160$. Then, from $P(X\leq 140)=1/4$, we get

$$P\Big(\frac{X-160}{\sigma}\leq \frac{-20}{\sigma}\Big)=\frac{1}{4}.$$
By the symmetry of standard normal curve, this means that
$$P\Big(\frac{X-160}{\sigma}\leq \frac{20}{\sigma}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}=0.75$$
According to your table, this means that $20/\sigma\approx 0.675$, and solving for $\sigma$, we get $\sigma\approx 29.63$. So, $X$ has mean $\mu=160$ and standard deviation $\sigma\approx29.63$.

Comment: I know this is nitpicking but $P(X\leq 160)=1/2$ gives median, not mean. They just happen to coincide for normal distribution:)

Comment: @C.Koca It is indeed nitpicking :)

Comment: @BrianChao why it is not  $P\Big(\frac{X-160}{\sigma}\leq \frac{-20}{\sigma}\Big)=P\Big(\frac{X-160}{\sigma}\geq \frac{20}{\sigma}\Big)$ ? I didnt get why $P\Big(\frac{X-160}{\sigma}\leq \frac{20}{\sigma}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @erez The first equality you wrote is correct, but that won't help you here; in order to use the table of values you provided above, it is necessary to convert the given information to something of the form $P((X-160)/\sigma\leq \text{positive number})=?$, which is what I did above. For your second question, call $Y=(X-160)/\sigma$. We know that $Y$ is a standard normal. So, $Y\leq 20/\sigma$ means either $Y\leq 0$ (with probability $1/2$) or $0\leq Y\leq 20/\sigma$ (with probability $1/4$).